# Question about rule syntax/format for CellularAutomaton function

Tags: syntax, rule, cellularautomaton

I am trying to understand how to use CellularAutomaton function. For example, I am interested in the Game life and I found a working example [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/gallery/implement-conways-game-of-life/). However I cannot understand or find a detailed explanation about the rule syntax/format.

By the link I mentioned above, this rule is used:

```
gameOfLife = {224, {2, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}, {1, 1}};
```

What does it mean and how to understand it? I could not find any explanation except this [link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalisticCellularAutomaton.html) about Totalistic Cellular Automaton, but this explanation is still not clear.

I do not need to understand the whole generic rule syntax/format for now. First, I want to understand only game life.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: This one https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellularAutomaton.html I read of cause. If you are asking this question, looks like you did not read it yourself :) This is one of the explanations for the rule argument: "general nearest‐neighbor rule with k colors". Looks like the authors of the documentation assumed, that everyone already have a PhD in this topic.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.